# How to set the IsEnabled to false when no mouse click on the listview row?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm facing one problem which is that I got one Listview which contain my editable bill record.
Every thing works fine when you click on row item the listvew first then click the hyperlink then it will work fine also. But when you didn't click on the item row in the list view then directly click on the "Edit" will not thing happen ?

How can I do so that when the user didn't click on the row item first will not allow the hyperlink to be click & if can turn it to gray colour?

I will attach my code at here:
The XAML FILE

```
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFF00FF" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>


    </Window.Background>

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
            <Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" Margin="-6,-2,-6,-2">
                <StackPanel Margin="6,2,6,2">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=BillName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate2">
            <Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" Margin="-6,-2,-6,-2">
                <StackPanel Margin="6,2,6,2">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=BillDescription}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate3">
            <Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" Margin="-6,-2,-6,-2">
                <StackPanel Margin="6,2,6,2">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=BillAmount}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate4">
            <Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" Margin="-6,-2,-6,-2">
                <StackPanel Margin="6,2,6,2">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=BillDueDate, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyyy'}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="MyItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
        </Style>


    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="lvwBooks" Background="White" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="130,97,5,39" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MyItemContainerStyle}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Bill Name" Width="100"  CellTemplate="{DynamicResource MyDataTemplate}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="250"  CellTemplate="{DynamicResource MyDataTemplate2}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Amount" Width="160"  CellTemplate="{DynamicResource MyDataTemplate3}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Due Date" Width="100"  CellTemplate="{DynamicResource MyDataTemplate4}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Edit" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <!--<TextBlock Text="Edit" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand"/>-->
                                <TextBlock>
                                    <Hyperlink TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Blue" Click="InputBox_Click" >Edit
                                    </Hyperlink>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>


            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

        <!-- It's important that this is in the end of the XAML as it needs to be on top of everything else! -->
        <Grid x:Name="InputBox" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.5"/>
            <Border
            MinWidth="250"
            Background="Orange" 
            BorderBrush="Black" 
            BorderThickness="1" 
            CornerRadius="0,55,0,55" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Title:" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Cambria" />
                    <TextBox MinWidth="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="InputTextBox" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lvwBooks, Path=SelectedItem}" Text="{Binding Path=BillName}"/>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button x:Name="YesButton" Margin="5" Content="Yes" Background="{x:Null}" Click="YesButton_Click" />
                        <Button x:Name="NoButton" Margin="5" Content="No" Background="{x:Null}" Click="NoButton_Click" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

The code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace HouseWivesSavior.HomecareModule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for EditBillRemainder.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class EditBillRemainder : Window
    {
        public EditBillRemainder()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ShowData();
        }

        public void ShowData()
        {

            SqlConnection conn;


            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["house"].ConnectionString;
            conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

            //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select * from bill ORDER BY BillDueDate", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
            da.Fill(dt);
            lvwBooks.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
        }

        private void InputBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // CoolButton Clicked! Let's show our InputBox.
            InputBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private void YesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // YesButton Clicked! Let's hide our InputBox and handle the input text.
            InputBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        private void NoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // NoButton Clicked! Let's hide our InputBox.
            InputBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope to receive respond & thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the question here....do you want to force the user to highlight the row first before they can click the hyperlink? If so then try this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Edit" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <UserControl>
                                <Hyperlink Click="InputBox_Click">Edit
                                    <Hyperlink.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
                                            <Setter Property="Hyperlink.IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Hyperlink.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Hyperlink.Style>
                                </Hyperlink>
                            </UserControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: I think this is what the OP wants +1, binding this way (from the Hyperlink side) is much simpler than binding from the ListViewItem side.

Comment: Thank you as your answer what I want~~